# WPF context menu whose items are defined as data templates

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, contextmenu, datatemplate

I have a list view that displays a collection of items, each item has as its underlying data a view model (MVVM).

What I would like to do is display different menu items within the context menu when the user right clicks one of these list view items.  The menu items displayed is dependent on the type of the item selected (i.e. the type of the underlying view model).

I would expect the below to work, but it does not (no items are displayed in the context menu).

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>                        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel1}">
            <MenuItem Header="DoStuffForVM1" Command="{Binding DoStuffForVM1Command}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel2}">
            <MenuItem Header="DoStuffForVM2" Command="{Binding DoStuffForVM2Command}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="{Binding}" />
</ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, I don't get any data binding errors either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me:

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" >
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>                        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel1}">
            <MenuItem Header="DoStuffForVM1" Command="{Binding DoStuffForVM1Command}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel2}">
            <MenuItem Header="DoStuffForVM2" Command="{Binding DoStuffForVM2Command}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
  </ContentPresenter>
</ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are setting the ContextMenu of the ListView, so your DataContext is the outer context of the ListView, rather than the ViewModel of an individual list item.

You need to set the ContextMenu of each item instead. For instance, using a style:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
      <MenuItem Header="DoStuffForVM1" Command="{Binding DataContext.DoStuffForVM1Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

However, the above does not account for the different types of menu.

If you are defining data templates for your listview for each type, the easiest way would be to define the `ContextMenu` explicitly in each `DataTemplate`.

If not, you'll have to do it with triggers in the style. You'll probably have to write a converter to be able to trigger on object type.

Comment: "If you are defining data templates for your listview for each type, the easiest way would be to define the ContextMenu explicitly in each DataTemplate." - How would I do this?  I do have explicitly data templates for each type, but when I add a context menu to the root display node of the data template (a grid in my case), the menu is not displayed.

Comment: This won't work. `ContextMenus` are in a different VisualTree than the rest of your application, so the `MenuItem` RelativeSource binding won't work.

Comment: @RobJohnson: You need to set Border.Background=Transparent in your grid to get context menus to appear on the whole grid.

Comment: @Rachel: Doh. You are right of course. I have got around this before now by setting the Tag of the ContextMenu with the outer context. (ps. Can I just say your WPF answers have helped me a lot over the last few months - thank you.)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Thanks! :) I still have a lot to learn about WPF, and find answering questions on SO helps me learn

Comment: @Rachel: Certainly agree with that. I find SO a fantastic way to think about things outside your comfort zone.