# Why doesn't this Binding work

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, attachedbehaviors

I have a 3rd party SplitButton control that exposes some DropDownContent and a boolean IsOpen dp to control whether the drop down content is shown or not.

In the case the DropDownContent is a StackPanel with several Buttons, each of which is bound to a command in the view model. In addition to executing that command, clicking the button needs to close the open DropDown content, which I am doing with the AttachedBehavior below.

But my binding, which simple needs to get a reference to the ancestor SplitButton control doesn't work. In the binding, you will note I am trying to Find the first Ancestor control of type SplitButton. I do see however that the debug info says ancestor level 1, so I changed the level to as high as 4, but still with an error.

Can someone see what the fix is?

## binding error

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 
>    'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.SplitButton', 
>    AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 
>    'CloseDropDownContentBehavior' (HashCode=8896066); target property is 'DropDownButtonElement' (type 'SplitButton')

## xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddNewPartyTemplate">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10">

        <toolkit:SplitButton x:Name="theSplitButton" Content="{resx:Resx Subject_AddNewWithChoices}">
            <toolkit:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
                <StackPanel x:Name="theStackPanel">
                    <Button Content="{resx:Resx Person}" Command="{Binding AddNewPersonCommand}" 
                        >
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <local:CloseDropDownContentBehavior 
                  ***              DropDownButtonElement="{Binding 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:SplitButton}}}"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Button>
                    ...

                </StackPanel>
            </toolkit:SplitButton.DropDownContent>
        </toolkit:SplitButton>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

## attached behavior

```cs
public class CloseDropDownContentBehavior : Behavior<ButtonBase>
{
    private ButtonBase _button;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        _button = AssociatedObject;
        _button.Click += OnPartyButtonClick;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        _button.Click -= OnPartyButtonClick;
    }

    // **** the point of it all
    void OnPartyButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { DropDownButtonElement.IsOpen = false; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DropDownButtonElementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DropDownButtonElement",
        typeof(SplitButton), typeof(CloseDropDownContentBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnDropDownElementChanged));

    public DropDownButton DropDownButtonElement
    {
        get { return (DropDownButton)GetValue(DropDownButtonElementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DropDownButtonElementProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnDropDownElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: why there is no Path in your binding? DropDownButtonElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:SplitButton}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing it's because `Interaction.Behaviors` isn't part of the visual tree, so the binding won't find the ancestor. Have you tried simply:

```
DropDownElement="{Binding ElementName=theSplitButton}"
```

Update from comments: the solution in this case is to simply use `x:Reference`:

```
DropDownElement="{x:Reference theSplitButton}"
```

Comment: Hi Kent. Yes, I tried that one first, no joy there either "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=theSplitButton'....

Comment: Mustn't be part of logical tree either, then. This would be a good case to use `{x:Reference theSplitButton}` but don't think that will work yet.

Comment: Hmmm, would an EventTrigger be part of the tree? How might that look if so (never used one).

Comment: Actually {x:Reference theSplitButton} works perfectly! Didn't know about that one. Cheers

Comment: Ah, yes, I see [it is in WPF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx). For some reason I thought it wasn't available until 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the SplitButton.DropDownContent but if its behave like a context menu the following answer might help: [WPF context menu whose items are defined as data templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083348/wpf-context-menu-whose-items-are-defined-as-data-templates)

this trick is to bind with RelativeSource Self or Type ContextMenu and then set the Path to PlacementTarget.DataContext.YourProperty